# Trying to display errors with jquery.validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to display errors using the jquery.validation plugin but I am not getting back any messages.

When I click on submit I get invalid alerts on the blank fields but no message in the summary div. Can anyone tell me what I've missed?

Thanks

```
 <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
  <label class="control-label requiredField" for="SW">
   Social Worker
   <span class="asteriskField">
    *
   </span>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="SW" name="SW" type="text" required="required"/>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
  <label class="control-label requiredField" for="NMN">
   Named Nurse
   <span class="asteriskField">
    *
   </span>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="NMN" name="NMN" type="text" required="required"/>
   </div>

<div id="summary"></div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">
    Submit
   </button>


<script>
$("#mform").validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $("#summary").html("Your form contains "
        + this.numberOfInvalids()
        + " errors, see details below.");
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You may want to check this answer of mine @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074380/how-to-add-form-validation-in-html/33074596#33074596

Comment: Thanks - the form does validate already and says the field Is required but what I am after is a summary "Your form contains X errors".

Comment: In that case..can you let me know what is `numberOfInvalids()` and `defaultShowErrors()`?

Comment: I guessed they were inbuilt functions - they were taken from the example page located here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#showerrors

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/4psggt9q/

Comment: Let me know if it works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Working Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/4psggt9q/

I have included `jQuery` and `jQuery Validate` plugins

Your JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#submit").click(function(){
        $("#mform").validate({
           showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

             $("#summary").html("Your form contains "
            + this.numberOfInvalids()
             + " errors, see details below.");
           this.defaultShowErrors();
        }
    });


  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="mform"> 
  .........other html code............
   // Observe that I have removed type="submit" below code
    <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" id="submit">
       Submit
    </button>
 </form>
```

`defaultShowErrors()` shows errors besides `input` fields.

`numberOfInvalids()` shows the count of all errors.

Comment: Thanks - this works perfectly for the example but doesn't work with the rest of the form I have here. It's clearly a problem at my end so I've marked this a correct and I'll use it to fix my code.

Comment: The problem with this answer is putting the `.validate()` method within a `.click()` handler.  Then you would **not** need to remove `type="submit"` from the button element.  The `.validate()` method only needs to be called **once**, and only on page load.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/j0qatxmf/